# React js pass objects to component in multiple map iterations

Tags: reactjs, parameters, components

The values do not arrive to the <Column component. The console.log lines print out the correct values to the console. If I remove the outer map iteration and fill up the variables with the same content the values arrive to the <Column component and I can use the values as props as usual. Why is that?

```
      <Container>

       {currentAdventure && currentAdventure.map((adventure, index) => {

        {this.state.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {
                const column = adventure.columns[columnId];
                const tasks = column.taskIds.map((taskId) => adventure.tasks[taskId]);
                  console.log("column.id: ", column.id);
                  console.log("tasks: ", tasks);
                  console.log("column: ", column);

              return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;

              })}
        })}
      </Container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return inside `currentAdventure && currentAdventure.map`.
Change curly bracket `{}` to parenthesis `()`

```js
<Container>

   {currentAdventure && currentAdventure.map((adventure, index) => {

    return this.state.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {
            const column = adventure.columns[columnId];
            const tasks = column.taskIds.map((taskId) => adventure.tasks[taskId]);
              console.log("column.id: ", column.id);
              console.log("tasks: ", tasks);
              console.log("column: ", column);

          return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />;

          })
   })}
</Container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I do that I get the following error: ':' after the this in the following line: {this.state.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {

Comment: or try just adding a `return` before the `this.state.columnOrder.map` in your original code

Comment: Perfect! Works brilliantly! What's the gap in my knowledge?

Comment: you are rendering this as a JSX, but you didn't return anything inside Array.map()